# Can I use a virtual mailbox on the physical and mailing address on an LLC's the articles of origination?

Tags: united-states, business, florida, limited-liability-company

I’m thinking of using a virtual mailbox like this to get mail for an LLC I'm starting:

https://www.incfile.com/virtual-mailbox

It will prevent me having to put my home address on the articles of origination for the llc formation. Also, if I use my home address, Orange County FL requires me to get the landlord’s signature for a business license and that won’t work.

Is that all okay, for example:

- Can I use a virtual address on the physical and mailing address on
  the articles of origination?
- Can I use my virtual address on the
  county/city tax receipt (aka business license) or will they reject
  it?
- Will a bank not work with me over this when I need an
  account/credit card?

Comment: No idea about the US, but I know companies in the UK that use their accountant's address, as another option if they're willing.

Answer (score 2):

> Can I use a virtual mailbox on the physical and mailing address on an
> LLC's the articles of origination?

No.

This is governed by [Florida Statutes § 605.0201](https://law.justia.com/codes/florida/2013/title-xxxvi/chapter-605/section-605.0201/) which states in the pertinent part that:

> (2) The articles of organization must state the following:
>
> (a) The name of the limited liability company, which must comply with
> s. 605.0112.
>
> (b) The street and mailing addresses of the company’s principal
> office.
>
> (c) The name, street address in this state, and written acceptance of
> the company’s initial registered agent.

So, you need a real life street address that is actually the street address of the principal offices of the business and the actual street address of the registered agent, which must be in the state of Florida.

> if I use my home address, Orange County FL requires me to get the
> landlord’s signature for a business license and that won’t work.

I am skeptical that this is the case. The requirement of a business license under local law, and the requirement to provide an address for state article of organization purposes is usually not the same. Business license requirements would only rarely apply to home based businesses that do not involve in person customer/vendor/employee contact at that location.

> Can I use a virtual address on the physical and mailing address on the
> articles of origination?

No.

> Can I use my virtual address on the county/city tax receipt (aka
> business license) or will they reject it?

I don't know. It would depend upon the tax regulations for that locality.

> Will a bank not work with me over this when I need an account/credit
> card?

A bank is ordinarily happy to use any address you provide them with if their economic requirements are met and the LLC is validly formed and has a taxpayer ID number from the IRS. Often a bank will need a "certificate of good standing" from the state secretary of state, affirming that the entity has not been dissolved and is current on its filing fees.